# What's difference between `javax.servlet.AsyncContext.startAsync()` and `new Thread(Runnable).start()`?

Tags: java-ee-6, java-ee-7

I have read the article [17.12 Asynchronous Processing](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm)

What difference between:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    AsyncContext acontext = req.startAsync();
    ...
}
```

and

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
   Runnable runnable = ...
   new Thread(runnable).start();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference lies in 'who' is controlling the thread. When you get AsyncContext from the request, use its start method and pass an instance of Runnable, the container manages the thread in which is executes the logic you passed in the Runnable instance. This is not the case when you fire a thread using new Thread(runnable).start()